# Realm Relationship Many-to-one not work

Tags: java, android, realm

I've a simple model:

class Dog
     Owner owner

And when I try to add two dogs with the same Owner, the fist dog that I've created his owner is null and the second dog do the owner.

Always owner is not null if the dog is the last.﻿

```
Owner me = new Owner();

Dog doggy = new Dog();
doggy.setOwner(me);

realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(doggy);  //here It has been created Dog doggy and Owner me

Dog jimmy = new Dog();  
jimmy.setOwner(me);

realm.copyToRealmorUpdate(jimmy); //here It has been created Dog jimmy and updated Owner me to Dog jimmy

....

RealmResults<Dog> dogs ...
dogs.get(0).getOwner();   //It's null
dogs.get(1).getOwner();   //It's Owner me
```

Why not work?

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you post your implementation of your dog class and owner class. The problem is most likely with your implementations.

Comment: No, I've already solved, the problem was that in realm when I did:

Owner owner = doggy.getOwner(); 
jimmy.setOwner(owner);

the owner of doggy become to jimmy and the owner in doggy is null.